# How to reduce the time taken to perform some operations on huge amounts of data using PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 200000+ rows of data in my database and I want every row's data to be checked with the other row's and perform certain operation and display the result.

Suppose consider the following table(tree data): 
p_teams

```
id  name  parentname  placedunder   position  

1    x       root         root         root    

2    y        x             x          left    

3    z        x             x          right  

4    a        x             y          left    

5    b        z             z          right
```

so on..

bonus table contains name and bonus.

example:

```
name bonus 
 x     10
 y     20
```

To get the total bonus of left and right tree, I should find the all the child's bonus respectively. So for which I need to check for the childerns. I have a logic it works fine for smaller data but as the data increases the time taken to execute the PHP function also increasing.

Here the logic(I have used codeigniter):

```
function getBous($name){
            $data = array('name'=>$name);
            $res = $this->db->get_where('p_teams',$data);
            if($res->num_rows()>0){
                $data = array('parentname'=>$name);
                $this->db->select('name,position');
                $res = $this->db->get_where('p_teams',$data);
                if($res->num_rows()>0){
                    $row = $res->result_array();
                    $i = 0;
                    $temp = array();
                    $temp1 = array();
                    foreach($row as $parent){
                        $temp[$i] = $parent['name'];
                        $position[$i] = $parent['position'];
                        $i = $i+1;
                    }
                    $abonus = 0;
                    $bbonus = 0;
                    while(sizeof($temp) != 0 && sizeof($position) != 0){
                        $data = array('name'=>$temp[0]);
                        $this->db->select('bonus');
                        $res = $this->db->get_where('bonus',$data);
                        if($res->num_rows()>0){
                            $row = $res->row_array();
                            $bonus = $row['bonus'];
                        }
                        else{
                            $bonus = 0;
                        }
                        if($position[0] === "left"){
                            $abonus = $abonus + $bonus;
                        }
                        else if($position[0] === "right"){
                            $bbonus = $bbonus + $bonus;
                        }
                        $data = array('parentname'=>$temp[0]);
                        $this->db->select('name,position');
                        $res = $this->db->get_where('p_teams',$data);
                        if($res->num_rows()>0){
                            $row = $res->result_array();
                            $i=0;
                            foreach($row as $parent){
                                $temp1[$i] = $parent['name'];
                                $position1[$i] = $parent['position'];
                                $i = $i+1;
                            }
                            $temp = array_merge($temp,$temp1);
                            $position = array_merge($position,$position1);
                        }
                        else{

                        }
                        unset($temp[0],$position[0]);
                        $temp = array_values($temp);
                        $position = array_values($position);
                        echo "<pre>";
                        echo "abonus:".$abonus." bbonus:".$bbonus." name:".$temp[0];
                        echo "</pre>";
                    }
                }
            }
            else{

            }
        }
```

So, what is the best way to solve such problems and How to deal with huge amounts of data?

Comment: i would suspect it would be more efficient to take this outside of codeignigter, at least it would be a lot easier to profile.

Comment: @nogad not are just not a good enough "codeigniter programmer".

Comment: What if your query was simplified: `SELECT p.name , SUM(b.bonus) FROM p_teams p  LEFT JOIN bonus b ON p.name = b.name WHERE p.position = "left" GROUP BY p.name;` ... then just do another query for position = "right". ??

Comment: using indexing can reduce the execution time to 50%

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much knowledge about your data structure. Still I would suggest using joins and taking it out of Codeigniter with the help of Stored procedures/ Views(I prefer views in your case). Using this, you can also remove complexities and increase the performance